# Ghostdoc doesn't attempt to generate return information

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ghostdoc

I've noticed Ghostdoc never seems to attempt to produce returns documentation. Given a method like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the departure date.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private DateTime GetDepartureDate()
{
    // TODO:
}
```

I'd expect it to populate the returns information like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the departure date.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The departure date.</returns>
private DateTime GetDepartureDate()
{
    // TODO:
}
```

I've seen [this](https://community.submain.com/forums/thread/1340.aspx) but this is quite old and to be honest, I don't really understand it. Any ideas?

Clearly it will never be perfect but anything is better than nothing.

Comment: Hi Robbie, what version of ghostdoc are you using?

Comment: @Ian We're on 2018.1.18330 (community)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Ghostdoc does not attempt to provide any text for return types.  However, you can set up a rule to do it, as suggested in the link in the question.

For example, to set a rule that adds a return description to any method with a name starting 'Get...' and using the rest of the method name for the text (as suggested in the question):

1. In Visual Studio, go to Tools > Ghostdoc > Options
2. Select `Rules` under `GhostDoc` in the tree
3. Select the `Methods` 'folder' in the right-hand Rules list (you may need to scroll the list)

Add a new rule to match methods starting with 'Get...':

4. Click `Add...` and `OK` to add a new 'Custom match' rule
5. Change the name to something like:

   > Match 'Get' methods
6. Click the `<any>` link after `method name` to set the condition
7. Select `starts with`, type

   > Get

   followed by a space, in the text box and click `OK`

Now, to set the 'returns' template text:

8. In the grid, click the ellipsis button `...` next to `<returns>`
9. Type

   > The

   followed by a space, in the 'Template text' box
10. Expand `MethodName` > `Words`, select `ExceptFirst`, click `Insert` and `OK`

The default summary text is overridden by the new rule, so to add something sensible for our new rule:

11. Back in the grid, click the `...` button next to `<summary>`
12. Type

    > Gets the

    followed by a space, in the Template text box
13. Expand `MethodName` > `Words`, select `ExceptFirst`, click `Insert` and `OK`
14. Click `OK` to complete the setting up of the rule

Ensure the rule is positioned below the existing `int GetHashCode()` rule so that the latter one will take precedence in that special case.  Click OK to close the Options dialog and you're ready to try out the new rule.